# Add an embedded barcode scanner onto fragment into my app via android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, barcode, barcode-scanner

So my goal is to put a barcode scanner onto my app to decode barcodes. I found a few answers using ZXing and Zbar but I either couldnt do it myself or the answer was a little out dated and half the code wouldnt work. I want to put the scanner onto a fragment and then have that 1st fragment send the decoded barcode to the 3rd fragment or results fragment. I added ZXing with intent then it prompted me to download the app and i dont want that.

Heres my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.macdaddydarian.pricematch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {

            case 0:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance("Scanner");
            case 1:
                return SecondFragment.newInstance("Location");
            case 2:
                return ThirdFragment.newInstance("Results");
            case 3:
                return FourthFragment.newInstance("User");
            default:
                return ThirdFragment.newInstance("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}

}
```

And the FirstFragment.java that I want the scanner to go on

```
package com.example.macdaddydarian.pricematch;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_barcode2, container, false);



    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));


    //FONT!!!!!!!!!!!
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "Blenda Script.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(font);
    return v;


}

public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

    FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
 }
}
```

And the fragment_barcode2.xml that goes with the first fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#1ab5ff" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFragFirst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/Scanbtn"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Okay and here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.macdaddydarian.pricematch" >

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And last the ThirdFragment.java i want it be sent to

```
package com.example.macdaddydarian.pricematch;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

  public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 

Bundle   

 savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragThird);
    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));



    //FONT!!!!!!!!!!!
  Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),         

 "Blenda Script.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(font);

    return v;
}

public static ThirdFragment newInstance(String text) {

    ThirdFragment f = new ThirdFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recently released a new [Android Vision Api](https://developers.google.com/vision/?hl=en) that provides barcode functionality.

You can view sample code of the API here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision

Comment: What sort of build issues are you running into?